# Getting Timeout::Error exception in a heroku worker

Tags: heroku

I know heroku has a 30 seconds timeout limit for the dynos. But for workers, I've been executing many tasks in the past for many minutes and I had no problem. Now in a new feature of an application, I'm seeing the process in the worker is removed (Delayed Job) with a raised Timeout::Error exception if the task takes longer than 30 seconds.

I want to confirm the maximum execution time for a worker in heroku.

Thanks

Comment: Good point I found a place where a Timeout::timeout(30) block was wrapping the call to the main function of the task (!!). It's solved, thanks Neil for the answer anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no request timeout for workers (or dynos for that matter).  Request timeouts for the users are handled by the Routing mesh.

Comment: Correction - the routing mesh allows 30 seconds to the first byte before returning an error.  The dyno will run as long as the request takes.