# Resque timeout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque

I am wondering if the workers have any kind of time limit of processing a job. I haven't found any info on the docs, so I would like to know:

Is there any time limit (timeout) for a Resque worker when processing a job in Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't, as long as your architecture or infrastructure don't impose it.

You must be very careful then. If your job can fall into an infinite loop, your queue will stuck.

It's also generally suggested to have minimum a couple of workers. Even better, consider to have different queues, one for slow or standard jobs, another for priority jobs.

Talking about Heroku (the original question did not mention it), [there is currently no timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861597/getting-timeouterror-exception-in-a-heroku-worker) for workers (only for web dynos). However [Heroku may kill your jobs](http://quickleft.com/blog/heroku-s-cedar-stack-will-kill-your-resque-workers) in some cases, such as after a deploy or restart.

Comment: I got a timeout after my background process ran for around 4 minutes...any other reasons Resque might have timed out?

Comment: @TimothyChen That depends on the particular timeout error. If it's resque itself timing out, then perhaps you have a plugin like [resque-timeout](https://github.com/openlogic/resque-timeout) installed. It's also possible that something inside your job (e.g. `Net:HTTP` or the `Timeout` module)  is throwing some kind of timeout exception, which in turn causes your job to end.